# Convert and Print Structure contents to a form in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, forms, data-structures

I am trying to print the contents of a structure onto a print page in Visual Basic(visual studio 2008). However my for each loop generates a conversion error? Could someone help me figure out whats wrong? Thanks

`Public Class Form1`

```
Structure IncomeRecord
    Dim IDVal As Integer
    Dim HouseholdNum As Integer
    Dim YearlyIncome As Integer
End Structure
Dim ArrayOfData(100) As IncomeRecord
Dim ArrayofDataIndex As Integer = -1

Dim PovertyLevels(,) As Integer = {{1, 10210}, {2, 13690}, {3, 17170}, {4, 20650}, {5, 24130}, {6, 27610}, {7, 31090}, {8, 34570}}

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub EnterDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EnterDataToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim IDVal As Integer
    Dim HouseholdNum As Integer
    Dim YearlyIncome As Integer

    IDVal = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    HouseholdNum = Integer.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    YearlyIncome = Decimal.Parse(TextBox2.Text)

    ArrayofDataIndex += 1

    ArrayOfData(ArrayofDataIndex).IDVal = IDVal
    ArrayOfData(ArrayofDataIndex).HouseholdNum = HouseholdNum
    ArrayOfData(ArrayofDataIndex).YearlyIncome = YearlyIncome

    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""



End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim PrintFont As New Font("Arial", 12)
    Dim HeadingFont As New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim LineHeightSingle = PrintFont.GetHeight + 2
    Dim Column1HorizontalLocationSingle As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim VerticalPrintLocationSingle As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim Column2HorizontalLocationSingle As Single = 300
    Dim Column3HorizontalLocationSingle As Single
    Dim PrintLineString As String
    Dim FontSizeF As New SizeF
    Dim FormattedPriceString As String

    PrintLineString = "Income Survey-Listing All Input Data"
    e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, HeadingFont, _
                          Brushes.Black, Column2HorizontalLocationSingle, VerticalPrintLocationSingle)
    VerticalPrintLocationSingle += LineHeightSingle
    e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, PrintFont, _
                          Brushes.Black, Column2HorizontalLocationSingle, VerticalPrintLocationSingle)


    For Each ElementString As String In ArrayOfData
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ElementString, PrintFont, _
                      Brushes.Black, Column2HorizontalLocationSingle, VerticalPrintLocationSingle)
        Column2HorizontalLocationSingle += 200
    Next


    Column1HorizontalLocationSingle = e.MarginBounds.Left
    VerticalPrintLocationSingle += LineHeightSingle

End Sub

Private Sub AllDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AllDataToolStripMenuItem.Click
    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Could you post the error text?

Comment: Value of type 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.IncomeRecord' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: Enter the debugger and check that value! The more info you post, the better the answers

Comment: Well I went through the the debugger but since the loop is never entered I cant see the values being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your for loop your ArrayOfData is of type IncomeRecord that is why it is complaining. If turn on Option Strict in Project Propertys Compile tab it will catch problems like above as you enter them. Give something like this a try

```
    For Each ElementIncome As IncomeRecord In ArrayOfData
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ElementIncome.IDVal.ToString, PrintFont, _
                      Brushes.Black, Column2HorizontalLocationSingle, VerticalPrintLocationSingle)
        Column2HorizontalLocationSingle += 200

        e.Graphics.DrawString(ElementIncome.HouseholdNum.ToString, PrintFont, _
                     Brushes.Black, Column2HorizontalLocationSingle, VerticalPrintLocationSingle)
        Column2HorizontalLocationSingle += 200

        e.Graphics.DrawString(ElementIncome.YearlyIncome.ToString, PrintFont, _
                     Brushes.Black, Column2HorizontalLocationSingle, VerticalPrintLocationSingle)
        Column2HorizontalLocationSingle += 200

    Next
```